# Linux - Split records and generate required format

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, scripting

I have hundreds of thousands of these records in a text file.

```
2015-05-16      testing112 alpha1        {}      {}      {beta1}
2015-05-16      testing124  gamma1   {xbgtd1} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
2015-05-16      testing124  asdasdg   {xbgtd1;dfdfgg} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
```

1. The file has 6 columns.
2. Space (one or many) is the delimiter between the fields.
3. The first, second & third fields are never empty.
4. 4th, 5th & 6th fields are enclosed between `{}`. IF there is no value, there are just 2 braces like `{}`. If these fields have more than one value, the values within the curly brace are separated by a semicolon such as `{a;b}`.

I'd like to do the below for each of the fields in each line

Loop through each line in the file & generate the following

```
1) <some sentence>field1, field2,field3;
2) <some sentence>field1, field2, field4;
3) <some sentence>field1, field2,field5;
4) <some sentence>field1, field2,field6;
```

In case of (2), (3) & (4) above, in case there are multiple values for the fields within the curly bracket, they are separated by a semicolon and like to generate the same statement for each of those fields too as below:

```
1) <some sentence>field1, field2, field4_first;
2) <some sentence>field1, field2, field4_second;
3) <some sentence>field1, field2, field5_first;
4) <some sentence>field1, field2, field5_second;
5) <some sentence>field1, field2, field6_first;
6) <some sentence>field1, field2, field6_second;
```

I'm trying to use perl to achieve this. However, the split of strings isn't coming out right. Am using something on the lines of `split(s/ {1,}//,$_)` as there can be any number of spaces between the fields. This is not working. I tried a few other options too that don't seem to work. Could someone please help me here?

Am running this on CentOS. Any language is fine with me to achieve the result.

Code below is what am using to parse and print to see the values before proceeding further to write to file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $i_file      =   'input.txt';
my $o_file      =   'output.txt';
my $text_cont   =   "";
our $ins_1  =   "";
our $ins_2  =   "";
our $ins_3  =   "";
our $ins_4  =   "";

open (FILE, $i_file) or die "Could not read from $i_file, program halting.";
    while(<FILE>) {
        (my $map_date,my $nam,my $ins_name_1, my $ins_name_2, my $ins_name_3, my $ins_name_4) = split(s/ \{1,\}//,$_);

        my $name1_refined   =   $ins_name_1 =~ s/\{|\}//;
        my $name2_refined   =   $ins_name_2 =~ s/\{|\}//;
        my $name3_refined   =   $ins_name_3 =~ s/\{|\}//;
        my $name4_refined   =   $ins_name_4 =~ s/\{|\}//;

        my @nam1_values =   split(';', $name1_refined);
        my @nam2_values =   split(';', $name2_refined);
        my @nam3_values =   split(';', $name3_refined);
        my @aod_values  =   split(';', $name4_refined);

        print "$name1_refined\n";
        print "$name2_refined\n";
        print "$name3_refined\n";
        print "$name4_refined\n";
    }

close FILE;
```

Comment: Please refer to [ask] for how to ask a good question. The long and short of it - in this case - is that showing us some code goes a long way to eliciting good and positive answers.

Comment: Show us the expected output for this input (not just vague examples) along with the code that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first part - I'd suggest you're over thinking it.

`split` with no arguments splits on whitespace.

So taking your input data:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   my @stuff = split;
   print Dumper \@stuff;
}
__DATA__
2015-05-16      testing112 alpha1        {}      {}      {beta1}
2015-05-16      testing124  gamma1   {xbgtd1} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
2015-05-16      testing124  asdasdg   {xbgtd1;dfdfgg} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
```

You get an array with:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '2015-05-16',
          'testing124',
          'asdasdg',
          '{xbgtd1;dfdfgg}',
          '{}',
          '{hjhjje;g76gr}'
        ];
```

Etc.

You can then apply a cleanup/split again on subfields.

```perl
 my @subfields = map {  s/^{|}$//g; split( /;/ ) } @stuff[ 3 .. 5 ];
print Dumper \@subfields;
```

This will - using `map` - split each element in fields 3-5 (remember perl starts at zero), and also remove outside squiggly brackets.

`map` is quite a clever higher order function, which is a *sort* of `foreach` loop, in that it 'transforms' every element of a list and returns a new list by applying the code block in to each item in the list in turn (and 'returning' implicitly the result of the last call, e.g. the elements out of the `split` function).

Giving (for last row):

```
$VAR1 = [
          'xbgtd1',
          'dfdfgg',
          'hjhjje',
          'g76gr'
        ];
```

So then you can:

```perl
foreach my $field ( @subfields ) {
    print "some_sentence $stuff[0] $stuff[1] $field\n";
}
```

Note - in the last row, it has skipped the empty field '5'. That's not too hard to keep if you need it. First thought on doing that is altering a the map a little:

```perl
my @subfields =
    map { s/^{|}$//g; m/./ ? split( /;/ ) : '' }
    @stuff[ 3 .. 5 ];
```

Which means your map now:

- Iterates elements 3 - 5.
- Applies a 'remove brackets' transform.
- tests if there is anything left
- either returns a `split` string, or an empty string depending.

Also - a couple of general points on your code - you'd be better off with:

- change that open to a 3 arg open with lexical filehandles. E.g. `open ( my $input_fh, "<", $i_file ) or die $!`;
- you can do `my ( $var1, $var2 ) = split;` instead.
- when you're numbering similar variables, that *often* means you want to be using a list instead.

So making code look a bit more like:

```perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $i_file = 'input.txt';
open( my $input_fh, "<", $i_file )
    or die "Could not read from $i_file, program halting : $!";

while (<$input_fh>) {
    my ( $map_date, $nam, @ins_name ) = split;
    print Dumper \@ins_name;
    my @subfields =
        map { s/^{|}$//g; m/./ ? split(/;/) : '' } @ins_name;
    print Dumper \@subfields;

    foreach my $field (@subfields) {
        print "some_sentence $map_date $nam $field\n";
    }
}
close($input_fh);
```

(You can remove the `Dumper` - it's there for printing diagnostics).

Comment: Thank you very much Sobrique. Appreciate your help. I usually bank on awk & sed for my work. Slowly trying to learn Perl. So a lot of beginners mistakes :)

Comment: We all start somewhere. I started on perl back when I had outgrown shell scripting. Both `awk` and `sed` are way more powerful than most think (most do 2 or 3 basic things with them), but I just never really grokked them in quite the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `foreach` loops will be like this the explanation I did in the code itself

`$_` is implicit variable for current element in `foreach` loop :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @splits;
open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die "unable to open file :$! \n";

while ( <$fh> ) {

    chomp;
    @splits = split( /\s+/ );
    my ( $field1, $field2, $field3 ) = ( shift @splits, shift @splits, shift @splits );    # get first second and third fields and remove from array

    print "<some text> $field1 $field2 $field3 \n";    #print them

    foreach ( @splits ) {    #@splits contain only 4th 5th and 6th field now

        if ( $_ =~ /\{(.*)\}/ ) {

            my $match = $1;

            if ( $match =~ /;/ ) {    #check if any of fields contain ;
                my @fields = split( /;/, $match );    #split with ;

                print "<some text> $field1 $field2 $_ \n" foreach ( @fields ); # print for each field

            }
            else {
                print "<some text> $field1 $field2 $match\n";    # print if field does not contain ;
            }
        }
    }
}

close( $fh );
```

Comment: Hello Arunesh - Thank you very much. Appreciate your help. Your solution works too. I'll use this logic elsewhere as needed. Thank you heaps.

Comment: Can I suggest - `split;` is generally a better choice than `split ( /\s+/ )`. Also - a chain of `shifts` isn't really necessary when you have `splice`
And also `split (/;/)` just returns a single value if there's no semicolon, so you don't really need the `if` there. And lastly - you don't need to specify `$_` in that match, because it's used by default anyway.

Comment: Thanks @sobrique I appreciate ur guidelines and will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

This Perl program will do what I think you're asking for

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sentence = '<some sentence>';

while ( <DATA> ) {
  my @fields = /[^\s{};]+/g;
  print $sentence, join(', ', @fields[0,1,$_]), "\n" for 2 .. $#fields;
}

__END__
2015-05-16      testing112 alpha1        {}      {}      {beta1}
2015-05-16      testing124  gamma1   {xbgtd1} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
2015-05-16      testing124  asdasdg   {xbgtd1;dfdfgg} {}      {hjhjje;g76gr}
```

#### output

```
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing112, alpha1
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing112, beta1
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, gamma1
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, xbgtd1
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, hjhjje
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, g76gr
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, asdasdg
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, xbgtd1
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, dfdfgg
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, hjhjje
<some sentence>2015-05-16, testing124, g76gr
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the awk version/ one liner. text is the filename containing data.

```
awk '{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){if(length($i) > 2) printf $1","$2","$3","substr($i,2,length($i)-2)"\n"}}' text | awk -F',' '{split($4,arr,";");for (i in arr) { printf "<some sentence>"$1","$2","$3","arr[i]";\n"}}'
```

Comment: Hello Shravan - Classy solution. Appreciate this. There's one problem. The output appears as - 100) <some sentence>2015-06-13,abcd,name_1,name_1; I don't want the serial numbers part & also, I want the name_1 printed just once.

Comment: modified answer  as removed the serial numbers. Give me the rows in which name_1 is occurring.

Comment: I think there's more to writing a one-liner than taking all the newlines out of a program!

Comment: @Borodin thank you for the clarification. I used to call awk commands as one liner.